# ReSharper: Find usage of a Page.aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net, resharper

Normally we reference a page using URL (e.g. login.aspx) when we create a form or a navigation menu... and when Re-sharper try to find the usage of the class (e.g. login), it doesn't find the places where I put that URL (e.g. unregister.aspx or index.aspx). I wonder if somehow we can make explicitly reference it. I don't know if we can't do it by ReSharper comment(something like this) and if it's recommendable or not:

```
// ReSharper THIS IS A USAGE OF "Login Class"
<a href="~/Login.aspx" ...
```

The only option that I can think of creating a static public property in the page (e.g. PageUrl) for store the page name. like:

```
public static string PageUrl = "Login.aspx";
```

and the usage will be something like:

```
<a href="~/<%=Login.PageUrl %>" ...
```

that will work! but still a little messy.

- Reason:

I am working in a big old project that required maintenance and when you change a page you may have to change the page that used it, because it's possible that you want to maintain the related pages too.

updated 8/8/2012

- Conclusion:

Based on the comments, especially of the one from Peter Ritchie, implementing a feature like this because the tools doesn't, it is not recommendable for many reasons (coupling,  complexity, time, etc), so this is worthless. Maybe a future version of Resharper or Visual Studio can include this feature.

The best alternative: it's to create a site map (for a developer).

Comment: I really don't recommend changing your design to facilitate "finding" usages with Resharper.  Resharper finds uses of classes (and members) not uses of URLs.

Answer (score 1):

This open source project might be a good place to start. It's meant to filter out unused images, but it should be pretty easy to change so it looks for unused files.

[Find unused images in VS Web Projects](https://bitbucket.org/jitbit/vsunusedimg/src/1079313d671d/VSUnusedImg)

Comment: +1. If it weren't for this answer I'd still be guessing why he needed to this.

Comment: @RobinMaben: It is a bit unclear, huh? Reading it a second time confused me too. Maybe there are benefits to skimming the content once in a while :-)